# Threads, the Python GIL and save/restore thread state

Tags: python, multithreading, gil

I'm working on making Python threads cooperate with SWI-Prolog threads, where SWI-Prolog supports fully independent native threads.   We are talking about embedding Python.  After initializing the embedded Python interpreter, the calling thread has a Python thread state.   To allow other threads, I need to call `PyEval_SaveThread()` and before working with Python again from this thread I need to call `PyEval_RestoreThread()`.   So, I **think** the logic is

- Thread M initialized Python.
- Thread M calls `tstate = PyEval_SaveThread()`
- If I want to make a call to Python

  - If I am thread M

    - If `tstate != NULL`, call `PyEval_RestoreThread(tstate)` and set `tstate` to NULL else call `PyGILState_Ensure()` (*recursive call*)
    - Increment `nesting`
    - call Python
    - Decrement `nesting`
    - If `nesting == 0`, save the state again using `tstate = PyEval_SaveThread()` else call `PyGILState_Release()`
  - else

    - call `PyGILState_Ensure()`
    - call Python
    - call `PyGILState_Release()`

While this seems to work, the asymmetry is rather inconvenient and feels fragile.   Is there some way to get in a symmetric situation such that I can simply get/release the GIL without bothering about the calling thread or thread state?

Comment: A little dubious, but it seems to work to initialize Python in a temporary thread that simply completes after Python initialization finishes.   So, there is no thread `M` :)  It smells like a hack and I don't know whether this has some unexpected consequences.   Can someone confirm this is safe from Python's viewpoint?